# MySQL "command denied to user for table" error and user permissions

Tags: mysql, case-sensitive, bitnami

When I run the following command:

```
SELECT p.*,
   (SELECT i.image
    FROM pimage i
    WHERE p.id = i.pid 
    ORDER BY i.id ASC
    LIMIT 1
   ) as image
FROM  products p
WHERE p.categories LIKE '%$subCatId%'
ORDER BY p.id ASC
```

on a database with the following tables:

```
pImage
products
sidebar
specs
```

I get the error:

> #1142 - SELECT command denied to user 'database_user'@'localhost' for table 'pimage'

which, unfortunately, was printed in plain text a dozen times across my production website this afternoon.

I tested it prior to release on a local version of the website, where it ran just fine.  I quickly reverted the change, and tested it on the development website.  It worked just fine on the development server when stored in PHP code.  I also tested it on the development server's phpMyAdmin interface, where it worked fine. I logged into the production website's phpMyAdmin interface, and ran the query there, and it failed with the same error.  I ran queries on each table individually, and they sailed through without errors.

What gives?!?

The production website is quite outdated.  It's running FreeBSD 6.4 (yes, EOL was November 30, 2010...) and MySQL 5.1 (yes, EOL was December 31, 2013...).  I am working on moving it from shared hosting so I can update it. The development server is the current Bitnami LAMP stack virtual machine, running Ubuntu 14.04 and MySQL 5.5.  Until now, I have had no compatibility issues.  As far as I can tell, the query doesn't use any syntax or special features that are different between the two versions.

Answer (score 0):

I logged into the database as an administrative user, and it returns the error:

> #1146 - Table 'company.pimage' doesn't exist

which quickly leads to a resolution for the original problem: A stupid case error between `pimage` and `pImage`.

## Case Sensitivity

This error wasn't detected earlier because the Bitnami appliance has the defaults changed to make it table names case insensitive, and because the error message for non-admin users in MySQL doesn't leak information.

The MySQL docs, [section 9.2.2 "Identifier Case Sensitivity"](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html) read:

> By default, table aliases are case sensitive on Unix

but this can be changed by the [`lower_case_table_names`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_lower_case_table_names) system variable.

> If set to 0, table names are stored as specified and comparisons are case sensitive. If set to 1, table names are stored in lowercase on disk and comparisons are not case sensitive. If set to 2, table names are stored as given but compared in lowercase...
>   On Unix, the default value of lower_case_table_names is 0. On Windows the default value is 1. On OS X, the default value is 2.

On my development server, `SHOW VARIABLES` demonstrates that the Bitnami appliance has this value set to 1.  `mysqld --verbose --help` suggests that the compiled defaults have this value set to zero, but, [as described on the bitnami forums](https://community.bitnami.com/t/why-is-mysqls-lower-case-table-names-variable-being-force-set-to-1/21986), `/opt/bitnami/mysql/scripts/ctl.sh` sets `--lower-case-table-names=1`.

## Cryptic Error Messages

The error message for non-admin users is cryptic:

> #1142 - SELECT command denied to user 'user@localhost' for table 'mispelled_table'

but the error message for admin users:

> #1146 - Table 'company.mispelled_table' doesn't exist

is easy to understand.  The admin user has the `SHOW GRANTS FOR CURRENT_USER` privileges:

```
GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'admin_user'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD [redacted]
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `company`.* TO 'admin_user'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION
```

but the regular user has the privileges:

```
GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD [redacted]
GRANT SELECT ON `schap`.`pImage` TO 'user'@'localhost'
GRANT SELECT, SELECT (view_count), UPDATE (view_count) ON `company`.`products` TO 'user'@'localhost'
...etc.
```

This last bit is just conjecture, as I don't have the necessary permissions to change and test it, but I think that the [`SHOW_DATABASES` privilege](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_show-databases) would give the user the good error messages.  It's probably good policy to avoid listing all the database names, as it prevents hackers from determining which tables exist as easily, but it sure makes for a lot of confusion!